# How do I upload a pdf file after entering an email?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a section on my site with a list of pdf files (it looks like this image 1). I need a popup to appear by clicking on the "download" button and there were inputs for the email and name. And only after the user entered this data, the download began.

I have a static site, so there is no need to do php sending yet. I'm just trying to make the download only after entering the email and name.

My popup is made with bootstrap. Here is the code for the individual item.

```
<article class="pdf-block__item pdf-block-item col-md-4">
            <div class="pdf-block-item__img">
                <img class="pdf-block-item__img-image" src="images/banner.jpg" alt="pdf-img">
            </div>
            <div class="pdf-block-item__title">
                PDF item test 1
            </div>
            <div class="pdf-block-item__text">
                In this eBook you will learn 21 key KPIs that will form the building blocks in
                your marketing reporting and how to develop the ultimate dashboard for your SaaS business.
            </div>
            <div class="pdf-block-item__button">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    download
                </button>

            </div>
        </article>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript validation for this.

First, you have to write a JavaScript function as given here and map it to the download button. After checking your Name and Email fields, you can redirect to the PDF document to download.

JavaScript validation: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_validation_empty_input.asp

Redirecting: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Note: If you use just a script without any server-side validation like using PHP, techie users can find the URL from the script and take the PDF directly.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Add a form in Your Popup modal with Required Fields and Then add the download button as submit button. And Add Your File URL in the form action.

Eg:

```html
<form action="Your_Download_URL">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" required> <!-- Name input with required tag -->
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" required><!-- Email input with required tag -->
<button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

This Will also Do Not Send any Form Data to Your Download URL.

Comment: yes it is a solution, thanks. But if I need to collect user data. Then I will not be able to send the data.

Comment: You Can Add a name attribute and the value you want to the Input field. Then It will Send Your Data to Your URL